# jquery sorround a selected element

Tags: jquery

I've selected an element

```
$(".body_inner:first");
```

Now I'd like to sorround this element with a Form element with other div element inside.

The result should be this

```
<form>
<div id="new"/>
<div class="body_inner"/>
</form>
```

Comment: So what's the original structure? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$('.body_inner:first').wrap('<form>').parent().prepend('<div id="new"/>');
```

It puts the selected element in a `<form>`, selects this `<form>` element and adds the `div` as new child.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('<div id="new"/>')
    .insertBefore('.body_inner:first')
    .next()
    .andSelf()
    .wrapAll('<form>');
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/h8NVW/**